# Split a Redis big ZSET

Tags: java, redis, jedis

We hava a Redis key. It's a *ZSET* structure named `test_key`.
The key is `userId` like `123`,`456`,`789`.The score is time stamps like `1474194838`, `1474194839`. Its length reached fifty million. We want to split it, just like `test_key_1`, `test_key_2`, `test_key_3`.

How to split it that can make the CRUD more easy?

We are java developer. The most frequently used Redis commodity is `zadd`, `zrem`, `zrange`, `zrangeByscore`, `zrangeByscoreWithScores`, `zcard` and so on.

Comment: Why do you want to split it? Split it into several small `zset` will make it's more complicated.

Comment: because it becomes more and more big, leading to the memory becomes  imbalance. We use redis-cluster and we want to load balancing. Spliting it can make it disperse to different redis instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to split the data into several Redis instances, then you need a proxy to dispatch the request to one or more Redis instances, and merge the results from these instances. The proxy can be implemented as a library or a service (e.g. a RPC server).

> Dispatch request

Say you split the data into 3 parts, and stored in 3 Redis instances. In order to ensure load balance, the proxy can use `MurmurHash` function to create a hash key for each `userId`, and dispatches the request to one or more Redis instances based on the hash key. Take `zadd` as an example: `zadd test_key userId score`.

1. Calculate Redis instance id: `id = MurmurHash(userId) mod 3`
2. Send `zadd` command to the corresponding Redis: `zadd test_key_id userId score`

> Merge results

When the proxy gets results from one or more Redis instances, it merges the results and returns to the client. Take `zcard` as an example: `zcard test_key`.

1. Get results from all instances: `zcard1 = zcard test_key1`, `zcard2 = zcard test key2`, `zcard3 = zcard test_key3`
2. Merge results: `zcard_res = zcard1 + zcard2 + zcard3`
3. Return the result, i.e. `zcard_res`, to client.

> Improve performance

In order to improve performance, when the proxy dispatches request to more than one instance, it should dispatch the request in parallel.