# High write concurrency backend for storing large set/array based data?

Tags: sqlite, concurrency, cassandra, redis, persistence

**The problem:**
I have a web service that needs to check membership of a given string against a set of strings, where number of elements in the set will be under constant growth, potentially numbering in the hundreds of millions.

If the string is not a member of the set, it gets added to the set.  The string size will be a constant 32 bytes.   Only one set variable is required, no other variables need to be persisted.

This check is performed as part of a callback on a webhook, thus performance is critical.

While my use case pretty much fits a bloom filter perfectly, I'm having trouble finding a solution to deal with the persistent storage vs i/o concurrency portion of the problem.

**Environment:**
DigitalOcean/Linux/Python/Flask, but open to change if required

**Possible Solutions:**

*redis*, storing the variable in a set, and then querying via `sismember` for a nice o(1) based solution.  This is what we are    currently using, but this solution doesn't scale well with a large    number of keys given that everything must fit in memory, and it also has issues with write concurrency when traffic increases.

*sqlite*, with WAL mode turned on.  concerned about lock contention when the server gets hit with a significant number of webhook    requests (SQLITE_BUSY).  Local server file doesn't scale across host machines.

*postgres*, seems like a nice middle ground solution, but might have to deal with lock contention here as well for write concurrency.

*cassandra*, given it's focus on write performance.  overkill for storing a single column though?

*custom bloom filter backend*, not sure if something like this exists that provides the functionality of a bloom filter with a high i/o    concurrency storage backend.

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot use any other database than those you listed?

Comment: No, I'm certainly open to other solutions.  We are a small two person team, thus have limited captial/management resources.

Answer (score 1):

The Redis solution can scale well with data sharding. You can set up several Redis instances (or use [Redis-Cluster](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial)), split your data into several parts, i.e. shardings, and save each part in a different Redis instance.

When you want to check the membership of a given string, you can send the `sismenber` command to the corresponding Redis instance. Take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556728/split-a-redis-big-zset/39586141#39586141) as an example of how to split data with hash functions.

Also, you can implement bloom filter with Redis (`GETBIT` and `SETBIT`). Just a reminder, bloom filter has the false positive problem.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense - and would definitely reduce write lock contention.   This is an easy problem to solve by throwing more money at it, just wondering if there's a "lighter" weight solution that works well on a single instance with medium traffic

Comment: Redis is single-threaded, you can set up several instances on a single machine to scale out. If memory is limited and you can ignore bloom filter's false positive problem, you can also implement bloom filter with Redis (there should be some open source project for that).

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to use `sismember`. Just do `sadd` systematically, and test the returned value. If it's 0, the value was already in the set, and so was not added. Doing so you will very easily reduce the number of requests to Redis.

Second, the description of your problem looks like a perfect match for Hbase, which is made for storing very large data set and query them using bloom filters. But you'll probably find it's overkill, just like Cassandra.

Comment: Thanks for the redis tip, that should help.   I certainly prefer working with redis in this case since it's lighter weight compared to Cassandra or HBase.    Just wondering if this is something that someone else has had to solve as well, assuming the resource constraints of a small team.